# Use replace to remove all DOM which included id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel, replace, replaceall

I need to export .xls but there are some elements I don't need in the table. Can I use replace to remove all DOM which included "id" elements?

Ttable

```html
<td>
<input id="id-1" value="111"><br>
<p">111</p>
<input id="id-2" value="222"><br>
<p">222</p>
<input id="id-3" value="3"><br>
<p">333</p>
<input id="id-4" value="4"><br>
<p">444</p>
<input id="id-5" value="4"><br>
<p">555</p>
</td>
```

I want to export like:

```html
<td>
<br>
<p">111</p>
<br>
<p">222</p>
<br>
<p">333</p>
<br>
<p">444</p>
<br>
<p">555</p>
</td>
```

I tried to use replace to search all id^* element, but I can't remove the DOM. I want to remove all DOM which included "id" elements in xls.

Comment: Why search via `id` when you could just do `document.querySelectorAll("p")` here? Then wrap the result in a `td`.

Answer (score 0):

picks up all the elements in the document that have an `id` attribute starting with the letters `id`. Then, it loops through each of these selected elements and removes them from the document.

```js
const elementsToRemove = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="id"]');

elementsToRemove.forEach(element => element.remove());
```

```html
<td>
<input id="id-1" value="111"><br>
<p>111</p>
<input id="id-2" value="222"><br>
<p>222</p>
<input id="id-3" value="3"><br>
<p>333</p>
<input id="id-4" value="4"><br>
<p>444</p>
<input id="id-5" value="4"><br>
<p>555</p>
</td>
```